# WooCommerce Orders: Is it possible to add another column and populate it with custom meta fields from Users?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

So short version is that I am trying to add an extra column in the orders page and have it populated with the custom field I have created for the users on the site (The name for the custom field is account_manager)

What I'm trying to achieve is for it display the customers account manager in a column in the orders section. Bit of a strange request I know!

I had a look at a few guides and tutorials regarding columns and meta data but it all seemed to be regarding the orders rather than data from the customer directly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't mind having a go, I just need a little guidance :)

I've tried this but it's not returning any values

```
function wc_orders_add_account_manager_column($columns)
{
    $new_columns = [];
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;
        if ( 'order_status' === $column_name ) {    // Change order_status to manage column orders
            $new_columns['account_manager'] = 'Account Manager';
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_orders_add_account_manager_column', 20 );


/**
 * Adds 'account_manager' column content to 'Orders' page
 *
 * @param string $column name of column being displayed
 */
function wc_orders_add_account_manager_column_content($column)
{
   global $post;
    $order_id = $post->ID;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Get the user ID from WC_Order methods
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();
    $meta = get_user_meta($user_id, 'account_manager', true);

    return $meta;
    if ( 'account_manager' === $columns ) {
        echo $meta ;
    } else {
        echo "Not Valid!";
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_orders_add_account_manager_column_content' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have stored this 'account_manager' as an order meta on postmeta table. You need to use `manage_edit-shop_order_columns` filter hook to add the new column to admin orders page and `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` action hook to populate this column.

```
/**
 * Adds 'account_manager' column header to 'Orders' page immediately after 'Order Status' and before 'Total' column.
 *
 * @param array $columns
 * @return array
 */
function wc_orders_add_account_manager_column($columns)
{
    $new_columns = [];
    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;
        if ( 'order_status' === $column_name ) {    // Change order_status to manage column orders
            $new_columns['account_manager'] = 'Account Manager';
        }
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_orders_add_account_manager_column', 20 );


/**
 * Adds 'account_manager' column content to 'Orders' page
 *
 * @param string $column name of column being displayed
 */
function wc_orders_add_account_manager_column_content($column)
{
    global $post;
    $order      = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    $user_id    = $order->get_customer_id(); // or $order->get_customer_id();
    $meta       = get_user_meta($user_id, 'account_manager', true);
    if ( 'account_manager' === $column ) {
        echo $meta ? $meta : 'Not Valid!';
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'wc_orders_add_account_manager_column_content' );
```

**Tested & It's Working**

**Note:** As I mentioned in the code comments, you can change the order of the columns by changing `order_status` in this code block:

```
if ( 'order_status' === $column_name ) {
    $new_columns['account_manager'] = 'Account Manager';
}
```

In this case, our new `account_manager` column will display after the `order_status` column

Comment: Not quite, ive added it as a user meta, in the simplest way what I want it to do is pull the users account manager and then add it to the order. I hope this makes sense im terrible at explaining things!

Comment: What is a example value of account_manager usermeta for a user? And what are you trying to do? Assign orders to users and show them in a column on orders page?

Comment: Ive made an update to some code i've salvaged, it looks right but isnt returning any values

Comment: So I work at a distributor and the idea is that when a customer places an order, it displays who that customers account manager is. That way our account managers can keep track of who has placed an order.